# SAS subtracting the most recent results from the previous ones

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to modify the function code so as to Subtract the result, e.g. today's Run_date from the previous one. However, my point is that it should only subtract the results from the same POLICY_VIntage, i.e. current (rund_date) 2021.01 - previous (2021.01). Not like the picture below where 2021.08 - 2021.09 for example
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i would like some like that
[image]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7k8Y.png


proc sql;   
create table policy_vintage_weekly as
  select 
    policy_vintage
    ,count(NRB) as number_policy
    ,today() as Run_Date format weeku.
  from PolisyEnd
  where POLIS= "W"
  group by policy_vintage
;
quit;

data policy_vintage_weekly_all;
set
  _work.policy_vintage_weekly (where=(run_date ne today()))
  policy_vintage_weekly
;
by policy_vintage run_date;
run;

%if &syscc. = 0
%then %do;


data _work.policy_vintage_weekly;
set policy_vintage_weekly_all;
by policy_vintage;
diff_value = dif(number_policy);
if not last.policy_vintage then diff_value = .;
run;
%end;
/* print report */
proc print data=_work.policy_vintage_weekly noobs;
var policy_vintage number_policy run_date diff_value;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL to join the current day's data and most recent prior day's data by policy vintage, then subtract the two values.

Example data:

```
data have;
    input run_date:date9. policy_vintage$ total;
    format run_date date9.;

    datalines;
02NOV2021 A 100
02NOV2021 B 200
02NOV2021 C 300
;
run;

data history;
    input run_date:date9. policy_vintage$ total;
    format run_date date9.;

    datalines;
01NOV2021 A 10
01NOV2021 B 20
01NOV2021 C 30
02NOV2021 A 100
02NOV2021 B 200
02NOV2021 C 300
;
run;
```

Solution:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
        select today.policy_vintage
             , today.total as total_today
             , prior.total as total_prior
             , today.total - prior.total as diff
        from have as today
        LEFT JOIN
             (select *
              from history
              where run_date < today()
              having run_date = max(run_date)
             ) as prior
        ON today.policy_vintage = prior.policy_vintage
   ;
quit;
```

Output:

```
policy_vintage  total_today total_yesterday diff
A               100         10              90
B               200         20              180
C               300         30              270
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem here is that I don't know what data previous is, because I run this code on the weekly and the result is append to the main _work.policy_vintage_weekly file. I would like to subtract the result for each policy_vintage let's say today () - the last run_date record

Comment: I updated the code to always pull the most recent value prior to the current day.

Comment: If I have Policy Vintage, it's dates.  It matters in the code in example u you to a b c e.g?

Comment: It does not matter. It's a join key as far as SAS is concerned. Whether you join on dates or characters, the join logic is the same.

Comment: Thank you very much tomorrow forest at work, but for now I can see that it should work. One more question after running your code example if I would like to add dataset today () to historical. Then this code is ok: `data _work.policy_vintage_weekly;
set
  _work.policy_vintage_weekly (where=(run_date ne today()))
  policy_vintage_weekly
;
by policy_vintage run_date;
run;`  _work.policy.... is my historical dataset

Comment: Yep that is okay and will ensure that you do not get duplicates of each run date, but your `by` group may be an issue in the future if your historical data ever gets out of order. You will need to ensure that both `_work.policy_vintage_weekly` and `policy_vintage_weekly` are always sorted or indexed by `(policy_vintage run_date)`. Otherwise, you can remove the `by` statement if it's not critical to store it in that specific order.

Answer (score 1):

This only needs to be done on the first of each policy_vintage.

```
data _work.policy_vintage_weekly;
set policy_vintage_weekly_all;
by policy_vintage;
diff_value = dif(number_policy);
if first.policy_vintage then diff_value = .;
run;
```

Aside: What happens if your process breaks one day and you need to re-run it the same day? What happens if there's a partial load?

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think about it, but I guess if I run the same day, this code has no effect on it, because the data is added to the library every day.

As for your code, I think I had this solution before, but it still subtracts my results between dates such as 2021.08 - 2021.09. And I would like it to only subtract from 2021.09 - 2021.09 e.g. or 2021.08.-2021.08 not reverse

Comment: Maybe do you have better option or suggestion. Im really new here.

Comment: Given your posted example this solution works. If it doesn't, please show how with example data so the code can be modified. I can ONLY test it against the data shown and output expected and from what you've shown so far this would work IMO.

Comment: FYI - I think you've made a mistake from the beginning here. I suspect you have a data set of full history somewhere and you need to just summarize that with a weekly variable each week. I work in insurance as well, policies are changed and updated all the time so using the date of an entry isn't useful, except in very rare cases. Usually you're aggregating on dates in the data set already, not adding the run date unless you're doing an ETL load.

Comment: yes excatly, So I need to compare week to week if any policies have renewed or expired. So I'm doing it completely wrong?

Comment: What would you advise me, at the top you have all my code from start to finish.

Comment: But I don't know your data sources/systems. I think you're using the wrong data source/set as your starting point. Go talk to someone in your company about the different data sets, explain what you're trying to do and ask them what approach they suggest.

Comment: Policies have dates, IDs etc to link up for this analysis, you wouldn't typically use summarized data for this type of analysis.